# Loading environment properties without vue-cli

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

I use .env file as described in https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code. Recently I tried to serve the built `dist` folder with nodejs, where my backend API is served. Vue app stopped working because the parameters are not defined correctly. I tried to copy `.env` file to the `dist` folder without luck. I tried to set them as environment parameters when running node in WebStorm - no luck as well.

How does Vue-CLI passes the environment properties to the browser? Is the `.env` file part of webpack? Probably yes:

> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can
> view them by inspecting your app's files.

Vue

```
VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE=cs
VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1

const {  VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT, VUE_APP_BFF_ENDPOINT } = process.env;
```

How can I keep this functionality when the Vue content is served with Node?

Comment: How are you building your application? Vue takes the env variables when it's building the production app, well, that's the way my applications work.

Comment: I have just found it  - I need to compile my app for dev environment!

Comment: You can change env vars in package.json: `"build": "ENV_VAR=new-env-var vue-cli-service build"` is this how you did it?

Comment: vue-cli-service build --mode development